# When use fanotify, files from deleted directory have incorrect path

Tags: linux-kernel, filesystems, filesystemwatcher, file-management, fanotify

When I use fanotify for listening to file changes, when I delete a folder in the root directory, the files under this folder appear with (deleted) characters, for example:

```
/data/service/el2/100/hmdfs/account/files/Download/test (deleted)/test
DELETE DIR
```

How to avoid this problem?

Comment: My linux kernel version is 5.11

Comment: Incorporate that additional information into the **question post** itself (via [edit]-ing it). Do not use comments for that purpose.

Comment: These are fanotify annotations. I was getting these and then wrote a filter to remove them from paths. But now I changed my fanotify code and am no longer receiving the annotations. If you could produce a code sample I could most likely see where you are going wrong.